# Asynchronous read from standard input

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, input, java-io

I'm trying to implement asynchronous input reading from console in Java.
Basically, I want to do this:

> 1. Spawn a thread T which reads on standard input with a readLine() on a BufferedReader
> 2. Continue with the program
> 3. After 10 seconds, stop T

The problem is the `readLine()` call in T, which I haven't been able to block.
Since interrupting the thread does not work, I figured I would try and send data to standard input from code, to unblock the `readLine()`.

So I tried the following: after 10 seconds, do

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
os.write("Unblocking line\n");
```

I thought it would work like this: I'm writing to the standard input as in a pipe, so the code in T should read `"Unblocking line\n"` and go to the next instruction.
Too bad, this doesn't work: "Unblocking line" is immediately shown on screen as if it was written to standard *output*, and it doesn't seem to affect the `readLine()`.

So my questions are:

1. Why is my reasoning wrong?
2. Is there a **simple, clean** method to achieve what I want to do? Please note that I'm aware of [this solution](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue153.html). Also, please do not suggest using `System.setIn`: it doesn't work. Finally, I should clarify what I mean by simple and clean: using only threads, and avoiding busy waiting.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I don't want to close the standard input, as I want to read again after step #3.

Comment: you have tried to interrupt the thread... have you tried to close the BufferedReader ?

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [`java.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to simply call

`System.in.close()` ?

Comment: No, I hate JVM on my linuxes

Comment: I edited my question. I would like to be able to use the standard input again after step #3.

Answer (score -2):

readLine() has to wait for a user to enter some thing. forever if nothing entered.
In your case, you want the thread to close automatically after 10 seconds if nothing entered I think! 
code your thread accordingly. Instead of waiting forever if 10 seconds went without user entering an input then main thread should close input waiting thread.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you'll see that I already tried to interrupt the thread. It does **not** work. I tried to *stop* the thread and it works... too bad, future calls to readLine won't work it I terminate the thread with stop().

Comment: That looks like a producer consumer problem. The two threads shoud run in synchronized blocks. One should wait(). Other should notify() after completing its work.

Comment: You are right. The problem is, **how** do I make a thread call a `notify()` if it is stuck on a `readLine()`?